# scraping data from specific Table Web/VBA

Tags: excel, web, html-table, vba

I created a macro that scrape Data from a local Web site of our Entreprise
the code works fine but the problem that this macro collect all the tables in that Page and what i want is to collect only a specific table in that Page

the html code of the specific Table  :

```
      <TD width="3%">&nbsp; </TD>

    <TD colSpan=4>
     <TABLE borderColor=#ffffff cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=3 
        width="100%" border=1>
     <TBODY>
     <TR class=TableTitle1>
     <TD vAlign=middle width=90 align=left>MOD Number (CIN)</TD>
     <TD vAlign=middle width=250 align=left>Title</TD>
     <TD vAlign=middle width=90 align=left>Leader (FIC)</TD>
     <TD vAlign=middle width=49 align=left>ATA</TD>
     <TD vAlign=middle width=72 align=left>Opening MP</TD>
     <TD vAlign=middle width=88 align=left>Opening date</TD></TR>
     <TR class=TableContent>
      <TD><A href="/cmh/consultation/preViewMOD.do 
      MODId=162615&amp;mpId=K20734&amp;isFrom=fromMP">162615</A> <A 
      href="/cmh/consultation/preViewCINData.do? 
      MODId=162615&amp;MPId=K20734">(162615/K20734)</A> </TD>
      <TD>COMMUNICATIONS-PAX ENTERTAINMENT INSTALL PANASONIC EX1/EXW ON 
      UNIVERSAL PLATFORM FOR ANZ06 VERSION </TD>
      <TD>SA CCC </TD>
      <TD>2333 </TD>
      <TD><A href="/cmh/consultation/preViewMP.do? 
       mpId=K20734&amp;isFrom=fromMP">K20734</A> </TD>
      <TD>08-Aug-17 </TD></TR>
      <TR height=1 bgColor=white>
      <TD colSpan=484></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD>
```

What I want is to Extract only that table with class: `TableTiltle1` and class: `TableContent`

this my macro VBA :

```
   Sub extract()

   Dim IE As Object, obj As Object
   Dim itm As IHTMLElement
   Dim r As Long, c As Long, t As Long
   Dim elemCollection As Object
   Dim eRow As Long

   'add the microsoft Internet Controls
   Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With IE
      .Visible = True
      .navigate "Try into another site because our site is "
      
       While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
      'we ensure that the web Page is loaded completely
       Set itm = IE.document.getElementsByName("searchById")(0)
       If Not itm Is Nothing Then itm.Value = "k20442"
       Set doc = IE.document


       Set tags = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

        For Each tagx In tags
        If tagx.src = "http://xxxxc- 
       xxxxx.airbus.xxxxxx/cmh/cmh/image/button_search.gif" Then
         tagx.Click
         End If
        Next

        On Error Resume Next
        Do While IE.Busy Or elemCollection.Length = 0
           DoEvents
        Set elemCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
        Loop
         With ws
          Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A1:AK500").ClearContents
         End With


        For t = 0 To (elemCollection.Length - 1)
          For r = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows.Length - 1)
            For c = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)

       With ws
       Sheets("Feuil1").Cells(r + 1, c + 1) = 
       elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
       DoEvents
      End With

      Next c
     Next r
    Next t

    End With
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
    MsgBox "Done"
 End Sub
```

Can anyone Light me on solving this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim oHtml       As HTMLDocument
Dim elemCollection    As Object

While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument
oHtml.Body.innerhtml = ie.Document.Body.innerhtml

Set elemCollection = oHtml.getElementsByClassName("TableTiltle1") 'or TableContent
```

Make sure to add the reference to `Microsoft HTML Object Library`.

Comment: hello @drec4s, just to clarify with you  : I delete syntaxe from Do While  to Loop and replace it by that or just replace SET elecollection as you mentionned with that script

Comment: Just the `Set` statement

Comment: I did it as u mentionned but when I run the macro it keeps looping without results

Comment: See edited answer. Replace your Do While Loop with this.

Comment: Yes I followed your instruction  see image https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=500673426375  ,, but no result sheet1 one is empty

Comment: If you print `ie.Document.Body.innerhtml`, is there a table with `class TableTiltle1` ?

Comment: sorry i'm newbie , what do you mean by print  , I meant how "syntax"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167415/discussion-between-drec4s-and-polos-tutorials).

Comment: can you  see the discussion ^^ :)